# Rails - Upload files direct to S3 via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

How can I develop an API in Rails that uploads files directly to S3? Everything that I can find via search and via existing gems uses jQuery, which obviously my API cannot work with.

Right now I'm using Paperclip to perform uploads, but this locks up a Unicorn process while the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been working on a project that has similar requirements and the solution I've used has the client (in my case an iOS app) uploading the file to a temp folder in our S3 bucket directly.

Assuming your model with paperclip attachments is called `Asset`, here is what we currently do:

1. Client uploads the desired file to S3
2. If the upload succeeds, the client then pings the API passing the details of the file location.
3. In our case the API creates/updates the `Asset` model with the path to download the S3 file and immediately returns.
4. We then launch a delayed_job process for the API server to fetch and process the file from our S3 bucket.
5. Once the processing ends we delete the temp file from the S3 bucket.

Here's some pseudo code

Client uploads file to S3 (in our case using ASW iOS SDK)

```
[[BSAAWSWrapper sharedAWSWrapper] uploadFileToBucket:url progressBlock:... completionBlock:...]
```

Send details of uploaded file to the API

```
POST "server.com/api/assets"
Parameters: {..., "s3_upload_path"=>"temp/UEA8zLE7FJ.m4v"}
```

API Controller

```
def create
  # create logic here
  @asset.delay.fetch_s3_upload
end
```

Asset model

```
class Asset
  has_attached_file :video
  ...

  def fetch_s3_upload
    url = "http://#{ENV['AWS_S3_HOST_NAME']}/#{ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/#{self.s3_upload_path}"
    self.video = URI.parse(url)
    self.video_content_type = "video/mp4"
    if self.save
      # delete temp file from S3
    end
  end
end
```